# File transfer dialog pops up while running zoom

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, zoom-meeting

I am not sure if this is the correct site to ask this question but this incident happened on my laptop running Windows 10.

My laptop was initially locked. When I logged on, I opened Zoom. While loading, I closed my laptop halfway (not locking it) to move to another area. When I opened my laptop, the file transfer dialog was opened at 92%. Below is a screenshot that I took:

[image: File transfer opened]

I tried clicking on cancel or details but nothing happens. Opening up Task Manager indicates that it is using Windows Explorer. Below is a screenshot:

[image: Task manager]

I am not sure if this is something I should be worried about. I turned off the Wi-Fi just to be safe.

Comment: Check to see if Zoom is updating - that may be all it is. There was a Zoom Update in the last 10 days. Also it could be a Microsoft update of some kind.

Comment: @John Yeap. Probably is. I was just worried that I was hacked.

Comment: I will post an answer as you have confirmed what I thought in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Zoom is updating - that may be all it is. There was a Zoom Update in the last 10 days. I saw this update as well.

Also it could be a Microsoft update of some kind, but I think it more likely Zoom.